# Return Object if True then use in loop

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, vba

I am using code to test if certain files exist and if they do, add their path and what their tab name will be (when I add them to Excel).  It works but right now it is a lot of duplicated code.  I want to create a method that I call and returns the object if true, and nothing if the file doesn't exist.  This is the code I have:

```
// Add Open_SI
if (File.Exists(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "OPEN_SI-en-us.xlsx"))
{
        FileInfo OpenSI = new FileInfo(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "OPEN_SI-en-us.xlsx");
        if (OpenSI.Length > 5000)
               File.Copy(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "OPEN_SI-en-us.xlsx", CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "OPEN_SI.xlsx", true);

        if (File.Exists(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "OPEN_SI.xlsx"))
               worksheets.Add(new WorkSheets() { Path = (CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "OPEN_SI"), TabName = "SI" });
}

// Add Pipe Sheet
if (File.Exists(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "Pipe_Supply-en-us.xlsx"))
{
       FileInfo Pipe = new FileInfo(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "Pipe_Supply-en-us.xlsx");
       if (Pipe.Length > 5000)
              File.Copy(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "Pipe_Supply-en-us.xlsx", CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "Pipe.xlsx", true);

       if (File.Exists(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "Pipe.xlsx"))
              worksheets.Add(new WorkSheets() { Path = (CurrentWorkbook.DataPath + "Pipe"), TabName = "Pipe" });
}
```

I repeat that code numerous times and if I make changes of course I need to make it to all of them. After that, I add them as tabs in excel with this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.Count; i++)
{
      excelApp.Run("CopySheets", worksheets[i].Path, worksheets[i].TabName, CurrentWorkbook.Version)
}
```

How do I reduce that code to a single method call?  Sorry if this seems simple but I have not created any methods that return objects on conditional statements yet.

Comment: Do you know how to create methods? How about returning simple results from one? Using conditions to return different results from a method is not much more complex than that... Just try creating a new method and let us know what exactly you're having an issue with.

Answer (score 0):

I would return the object if true, and null otherwise.

something like this:

```
MyType CheckFile(string fn){
   MyType myObject = new MyType();
   if(File.Exists(fn))
   {
       //do work
       return myObject;
   }else{
       return null;
   }
}
```

And to use it would be something like:

```
string[] files = {"file1.xlsx","file2.xlsx"};
for(int i=0;i<fiels.Count;i++){
    MyType obj = CheckFile(files[i]);
    if(obj != null){
       //object exists, do some work
    }else{
       //object doesn't exist, do alternative work
    }
}
```